# Connecting Google Home To Arduino - Issues with ground

Tags: power-supply, arduino, voltage, audio, ground

I am attempting to connect my google home to an Arduino so I can read when the speaker is on. (This will control a Big Mouth Billy Bass but that is not relevant here.)

When the speaker (google home) in plugged in to its own power supply the circuit works perfectly, but when I try to power it in parallell with a 12v=>5v converter it turns off whenever the speaker is activated. Please see images for a visual of this. My appologies for the drawing's quality.

Working but using 2 different plugs:[image: Working but using 2 different plugs]

Not working - Google Home turns off whenever it uses the speaker - using one plug:[image: Not working - Google Home turns off whenever it uses the speaker - using one plug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are both sides of the speaker are driven (neither is ground).  This means when you connect to the Arduino with a common USB ground, you are shorting one side of the amplifier to ground.

Your best solution would be to use an audio isolation transformer between the two to provide complete electrical isolation.  They can be found by searching for "audio isolation transformer" or "audio ground loop isolator".

Possible solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWjDq4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Take a look at the A1/A2 ADC values with off/on, you should get an easily detectable pattern.

Using an isolation transformer with an Arduino analog input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiSIHu.png)</sup>

The resistor divider generates a 2.5V reference, since the voltage on the transformer secondary will be AC we need to move it up above 0V at the center (the Arduino ADC can't measure negative voltages).  The transformer primary is just connected across the speaker in the Google Home.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I believe that yes, both sides are driven. I will look into an audio isolation transformer. Do you know why this would work when they are plugged in individually though?

Comment: Depending on what exactly needs to be measured, a normal (cheap) optical isolator with separate grounds and a pull up or pull down on the Arduino side might also work.

Comment: Each signal is probably driven between 0V and VCC (which might be 5V on the google device).  The two signals are likely driven with the same signal inverted, so if you measure the signal against ground you will get the proper audio signal.  The catch is that with the large loop formed by the signal wire and the ground loop, you will almost certainly have ground loop EMI problems (noise pickup).

Comment: There are also analog opto isolators which will do the job depending on what you are building.  Many audio devices will power down the audio amp when inactive, so you can run one of the audio lines through an RC filter (large R) and you will see 0V when off and (probably 2.5V when on).  All speculation, but I use this technique on other devices with good results.

Comment: @DeanFranks can you go into a bit more detail here? I am not familiar with these parts (but am looking into it currently). I am trying to see how this would work.

Comment: If you are building one, just use the circuit above or an isolation transformer with the secondary connected between Arduino ground and an analog input.  The circuit above may or may not work, and may work on some revisions of the hardware and not others.  The transformer is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Or use an isolated DC-to-DC to power the Arduino to isolate the grounds, that would work too.

Comment: @DeanFranks Do I need a specific component for isolated DC-to-DC? And is the circuit above detailing an optical isolator or audio isolation transformer. In the diagram above would I be reading both A1 and A2 and take the difference?

Comment: I bought some audio isolation transformers but am a bit confused on how to wire them up. I am using 2 like in this diagram but am unsure where to have IN- go to https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33888219/55292975-271dd100-53f1-11e9-81a8-1c2e1ce9a98d.jpg

Comment: The first circuit pictured above did not work but the second pictured worked great. It sets the default A0 reading to 512 and has clear readings. Thank you.